# Reading lines in two diffrent text Files and writing it to another text

Tags: python

I have wrote a little simple Python script that should read from 2 different text files and output the two lines in to a new text file also with some text in the front and the end of each line. It works with the `bline` but for some reason it only reads the the first line in `aline`.

```
import os

f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
f3 = open('new_file_name.txt','w')
for aline in f1:
    aline = aline.rstrip()
    for bline in f2:
        bline = bline.rstrip()
        f3.write('\n'"start %s:%s end" % (aline, bline))
```

file1 input:

```
1234
5678
9012
```

file2 input:

```
5678
9012
3456
```

new txt file should be:

```
start 1234:5678 end
start 5678:9012 end
start 9012:3456 end
```

but instead it is:

```
start 1234:5678 end
start 1234:9012 end
start 1234:3456 end
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: You are looping through all 3 lines in `f2' for each line in `f1`. Try reading the two files first and store your data in a list of string, then store in the output file

Answer (score 1):

```py
file_1 = open('file1.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
file_2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

file_3 = []  # as list so we can dump it all at once
for segment in zip(file_1, file_2):
  file_3.append(f'start {segment[0]}:{segment[1]} end')
  
open('file3.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(file_3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through the first one and then looping through the second one. This means that you're creating a bunch of combinations.

What you can do is use the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function between the two files.

```py
for aline, bline in zip(f1, f2):
    aline = aline.rstrip()
    bline = bline.rstrip()
    f3.write('\n'"start %s:%s end" % (aline, bline))

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close() # Remember to close!
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to `zip` both `f1` and `f2` so to get both of their values for each line at the same time and then write them to `f3`:

```py
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('new.txt', 'w') as f3:
    for a_line, b_line in zip(f1, f2):
        f3.write(f'start {a_line.rstrip()}:{b_line.rstrip()} end\n')
```

Also it is suggested that you use context manager (`with`) to open files (it also automatically closes them when you exit out of the block).